# WPF Gantt chart control

Tags: c#, wpf, controls, gantt-chart

In my project I need to have higly editable gantt control. I know that world is full of them and I've found some and use some.

I've already lost much of my time with syncfusion, it's not a good chart. I want something that enable me to edit many things, add more columns in table etc.

Could You tell me about good Gantt charts You've used? It may be not-free. If it's good, my company will buy it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/) or [DevExpress](http://www.devexpress.com/). See if these fits your needs.

Comment: I have not used Gantt Chart, but many other from Telerik like VirtualizingWrapPanel, and these are really feature rich, so I suggested these. They offer trials, try it and see.

Comment: I don't think DevExpress has a WPF Gantt control. This was asked only 9 months ago on their forums. https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T186620

Answer (score 0):

This is a vendor-biased answer. The experience of our customers is that WPF Gantt charts actually look very nice but that they tend to struggle when it comes to "real life" scenarios, in which you want to see and change thousands of data at highest speed. Hence, we have learned from our customers that they prefer to embed a proven .NET/C# Gantt control into their WPF applications. They compromise the brightest look and feel against reliability, performance and being "industry-proof".

Our customers use the product called VARCHART XGantt: http://www.netronic.com/products/varchart-xgantt/overview.html

Does this help you?

Answer (score 0):

The Plus edition of [Office Timeline](https://www.officetimeline.com/plus) allows you to synch your PowerPoint Gantt chart with your MS Project or Excel data. You can download the free version, play around with it and see if it fits your needs and then decide if you want to go for the Import and Synch features which are only available in the Plus, paid version.